# Getting the name of selected file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-input

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/b5pfX/)'s the fiddle. I have a project where I am making non-styleable form elements,[GitHub](http://github.com/JJP123/BlueBeard), and right now I am making a file input. You can find the source codes at the bottom of the question. I have used `opacity: 0;` on the input, and put a `<span></span>` over it. The extra space in the `span` is for the name of the file selected, but I am trying to think of a way to retrieve the file name using JavaScript or jQuery.

HTML:

```
<span>Choose File<input type='file'></span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #252525;
    color: #96f226
}
span {
    background: #4a4a4a;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
none yet
```

Comment: These sites might be able to help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can bind the onchange event of the file input to a function, and inside that function extract the name of the file.

Here is your html, with some id's for simple jquery access:

```
<span id="fileText"><input type='file' id="file">Choose File</span>
```

And some jQuery code:

```
$("#file").on("change", function()
{
    var value = this.value.split(/[\/\\]/).pop();
    $("#fileText").append(value);
});
```

Basically, this function will extract the filename from the input (this.value), then select the text after the last slash (directory).

The split() call uses a regexp to split the text into an array at either a forward slash or backward slash (i'm not sure if it is ever a forward slash, but just to be safe). If you just want to split it at the backward slashes, you don't have to use a regular expression, just call split("\"). the pop() returns the last item in the array.

Then, we append this new text to the end of the span.